# Replace with string if it starts with string in another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of words: `X` and `Y`. I would like to replace words in list X  by words in list Y if, and only if, the word in list X is exactly the same as the first part of the word in list Y.

For example, I want to replace the word 'engage' (list X) by the word 'engagement' (list Y). My lists are below:

```
X=['les', 'engage', 'du', 'dent', 'de', 'la', 'que', 'sont', 'aussi', 'ceux', 'des', 'dirigeants', 'de', 'la', 'société', '»', 'ferroviaire', ',', 'a-t-il', 'soutenu', 'de', 'des', 'élus', 'du', 'grand-est', 'réunis', 'à', 'l', '’', '.', 'le', 'président', 'de', 'la', 'république', ',', '(', 'à', 'droite', ')', ',', 'aux', 'tés', 'du', 'patron', 'de', 'la', 'sncf', ',', 'guillaume', ',', 'à', 'la', 'gare', ',', 'à', 'paris', ',', 'le', '1er', 'juillet', '2017.', 'van', 'der', 'l', '’', 'irrita', 'qui', ',', 'par', 'fois', ',', 's', '’', 'des', 'usa', 'de', 'la', 'sncf', 'face', 'aux', 'trains', 'suppri', 'ou', 'aux', 'dessertes', 'abandonnées', 'semble', 'avoir', 'aussi', 'saisi', 'le', 'président', 'de', 'la', 'république', '.', 'devant', 'des', 'élus', 'du', 'grand-est', ',', 'réunis', 'mardi', '26', 'février', 'à', 'l', '’', 'dans', 'le', 'cadre', 'du', 'grand', 'débat', ',', 'a', 'eu', 'des', 'mots', 'très', 'durs', 'contre', 'la', 'sncf', ',', 'qui', 'a', 'fermé', 'la', 'ligne', 'saint-dié', '-', 'le', '23', 'décembre', '2018', ',', 'alors', 'que', 'le', 'chef', 'de', 'l', '’', 's', '’', 'était', 'engagé', ',', 'durant', 'un', 'dans', 'les', 'tué', 'en', 'avril', '2018', ',', 'à', 'ce', 'qu', '’', 'elle', 'reste', 'opération', '.']
Y=['levant', 'lamés', 'devant', 'quenelle', 'irritation', 'cenelle', 'usagers', 'lavant', 'avant', 'opérationnelle', 'supprimés', 'engagements']
```

For this, I have to compare item by item of the two lists and replace items, right? How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried any thing so far? people are more willing to help when the poster has made an attempt first

Comment: try some googling and make some attempt to solve your problem. Then update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the solution already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over both lists, and select a given string from `Y` if it [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/string-methods.html) a given string in `X` and `break` so you don't have to loop over all values in `Y`, or otherwise keep the string from `X`:

```
X = ['les', 'engage', 'du', 'dent', 'de', 'la'...
Y = ['levant', 'lamés', 'devant', 'quenelle', 'irritation'...

l = []
for x in X:
    for y in Y:
        if y.startswith(x):
            # append y if the string starts with x
            l.append(y)
            # First match. Break to next x
            break
    # for-else statement
    # If no strings in y begin with x, append x
    else: 
        l.append(x)
```

---

**Output**

```
['les', 'engagements', 'du', 'dent', 'devant'...
```